# Selective Rails 3.2 asset pipeline compression per file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, angularjs

I'd like to selectively compress some of the javascript files in a Rails 3.2 app, but still have all js assets served from a single bundled file in the production environment.

Syntax like this, inside of the app/assets/javascripts/application.js file, using the **made-up** `:compress => false` option passed to the last 3 sprockets `require` directives I hope explains what I'm trying to achieve.

```
// Contents of app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular-1.0.1/angular, :compress => false
//= require angular-1.0.1/angular-resource, :compress => false
//= require products, :compress => false
```

So jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js files will be compressed (by Rails asset compilation, which uses UglifierJS by default), and the remaining 3 files will not be compressed, but they will be bundled into the application.js bundle.

Is there any way available to do this?

The motivation is that the products.js file contains an angularjs controller that makes use of angular's dependency injection which requires specific variable names such as `$scope` and `$http` are not altered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using this line in my **config/environment/production.rb** file

`config.assets.js_compressor = Sprockets::LazyCompressor.new { Uglifier.new(:mangle => false) }`

It compress my controllers but it doesn't change method signatures so DI still works as expected.

Comment: Many thanks Milan, works for me in Rails 3.2.6, angularjs works fine now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the `Sprockets::LazyCompressor` part do?

Comment: Almost everything in rails is just "shell" every concrete implementation of specific pattern is generalised so you can switch to alternative. Sprockets is engine which do compression, sass/less precompilation... and many other things. The the line Sprockets::LazyCompressor.new creates lazy loader for js compression, and you can use anything. By default with rails you are using uglifier to compress your files and line above is just way to tell uglifier to avoid renaming method arguments.

Comment: Of course, alternative to this solution is to use explicit injection with strings, and below you can find Jiří Pospíšil response how to write code which can be minified completely with uglifier.

Answer (score 6):

To get this to work with Rails 4 since it uses a newer version of sprockets I used:

`config.assets.js_compressor  = Uglifier.new(mangle: false) if defined? Uglifier`

in environments/production.rb

Answer (score 3):

Note that for this specific reason there's an option to specify the injected services with strings rather than variable names. See the line under the controller.

```
var MyController = function(renamed$scope, renamedGreeter) {
  ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
```

Example taken from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di