# Rails 3.2 exclude single JS file from minification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minify

How can I tell Rails to not minify a particular JS file?

I have a file that I've stored in app/assets, and it is already minified. I do not have access to an unminified version of the file. Minifying it again causes browser errors, so I would like to skip the minification for this one file, while still having it appended to the compiled application.js file.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061575/rails-3-1-pipeline-exclude-javascript-file

Comment: there is an excellent tools for Google you can use it for minify any js file https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api

Comment: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922692/selective-rails-3-2-asset-pipeline-compression-per-file